# Liferay - Access GET or POST parameters from ASSET PUBLISHER velocity template

Tags: post, get, liferay, velocity

Is there any way how to access GET or POST parameters from ASSET PUBLISHER velocity template?

For example, if I have one asset publisher on site /announcements, i need to access GET parameters for example: /announcements?display=maximized.

Is there any solution how to access 'display' parameter from velocity template in asset publisher?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I have found the right solution. In VM template we need to use this command:

```
$portalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest($request).getParameter('parameter-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my liferay theme I am getting request parameters this way:

`$request.getParameter("display")`

So you may try the same in your template file.

Comment: This is not working in assetpublisher template, but thanks - I have found solution (below).